# How to handle array with split and substring and foreach

Tags: powershell

How to handle array with split and `substring` and `foreach` to output below information.

I have tried with split and `substring`. But still not work. Thanks.

```
$item=$item.ToString() 
$driveID=$item.Substring(0,26) 
$ID=($driveID.Split(":")[-1]).trim()
$status=$item.Substring(27,$item.Length-1-27)
$stauts1=($status.split(",")[-1]).trim()
```

**input【array】:**

```
physicaldrive 1I:1:9 (port 1I:box 1:bay 9, SAS HDD, 900 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:10 (port 1I:box 1:bay 10, SAS HDD, 900 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:11 (port 1I:box 1:bay 11, SAS HDD, 2.4 TB, OK, spare)
physicaldrive 1I:1:12 (port 1I:box 1:bay 12, SAS HDD, 900 GB, OK, shared spare)
```

**Expected output:**

```
DriveID DriveStatus
9  OK
10 OK
11 OK
12 OK
```

Comment: [1] is the drive id the same as the bay number? [2] PLEASE format your code & data properly. there is link to the instructions on the page that you used to create your question.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey,  thank you very much. I've learned a lot from you

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following presumes the `DriveID` is the number after the word `bay`. the code grabs named capture groups and uses them to make a PSCustomObject. that is then sent to the `$DriveInfo` collection, and finally displayed on screen. at that point you can easily export it. [*grin*]

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
physicaldrive 1I:1:9 (port 1I:box 1:bay 9, SAS HDD, 900 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:10 (port 1I:box 1:bay 10, SAS HDD, 900 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:11 (port 1I:box 1:bay 11, SAS HDD, 2.4 TB, OK, spare)
physicaldrive 1I:1:12 (port 1I:box 1:bay 12, SAS HDD, 900 GB, OK, shared spare)
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file


$DriveInfo = $InStuff.ForEach({
    $Null = $_ -match '^.+:bay (?<DriveID>\d+), .+b, (?<Status>.+).+$'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DriveID = $Matches.DriveID
        Status = $Matches.Status.Split(',')[0]
        }
    })

$DriveInfo
```

output ...

```
DriveID Status
------- ------
9       OK    
10      OK    
11      OK    
12      OK
```